# Designing IO adapters for web interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns, io, adapter

I have a Java application which consist of a set of services. These services require I/O which is handled through an IOAdapter interface as below:

```
interface IOAdapter {
    void info(Object arg);
    void error(Throwable cause);
    String read(String prompt);
    boolean confirm(String prompt);
}
```

In the service methods, the input is obtained using some implementation of the adapter which is composed into the service instance. This adapter then handles all I/O (user interactions), and hence allows separation of that concern from the actual business logic.

For example, a typical method method would do something like:

```
class MyService {

    IOAdapter adapter;

    MyService () {
        adapter = new MyAdapter();  // some implementation
    }

    void doSomething() {
        try {
            ...
            String val = adapter.read("Enter a value: ");
            if(adapter.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                adapter.info("Value entered is: " + val);
                ...
            } else {
                doSomething();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            adapter.error(e);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was able to implement an adapter which does I/O through the Java console. But, can anybody suggest a possible approach if I were to provide an implementation for a Web based adapter where the I/O happens through the browser?

Is there an alternative approach which would help solve this problem in a more straight-forward manner?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you want to wrap the functionality of an HTTP server in your own service, implementing the `IOAdapter` interface. I think that this is not "beautiful" in the way the `interface IOAdapter` is written and used in the `MyService` class. This is because even if you write a `MyHTTPAdapter` the `adapter.read` method cannot be implemented using HTTP.

In HTTP we have **two entities** communicating. The **client** sends and the **server responds**. This cannot be modelled using this interface you propose, since you model only one entity and have only one method for exchanging data, method `read`. You have to alter the interface design, focusing on a client-server design, then you could wrap an HTTP communication.

EDIT:
Integrating the two paradigms of communication (console communication and HTTP communication) is not a trivial task. I would propose a design imposed by this `interface`, following the client-server architecture imposed by HTTP, supposing that a console application could implement it too:

```
//This should be implemented by either the HTTP or the console server Adapter
interface IOAdapter {
    IOResponse serveRequest(IORequest request);
}

//This interface should be implemented by both models of IOAdapter
//For example, a subclass of string could also implement this interface in 
//order to unify the two models
interface IORequest {
}

//This interface should be implemented by both models of IOAdapter
//For example, a subclass of string could also implement this interface in 
//order to unify the two models
interface IOResponse {
}
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: You have precisely pointed out the difference in the architecture between the console based and the web-based use cases. Could you suggest an alternative architecture / design change which would still help provide one interface catering to both paradigms? Or is it unfeasible, and each should have their own ways to perform I/O?

Comment: As you can see on my edit, I would propose following the HTTP paradigm as it is more strict than the console paradigm

Comment: Hmm, wonder if this will work in my case - I am looking for more of a server side push event - which does not need to respond to a client request, but pushes from the server side itself...